# Geospatial search in microservices - GET or POST?

Tags: microservices

This was very often in the past center of discussion, whether to use `GET` or `POST` for searchin.

If you are making for example geospatial request, both values are needed (lat and long). If you do it with `GET`, you cannot really annotate in openapi that both fields should be dependent on each other - the whole group lat/lon/distance required if one of them set. However there are some [opened tickets](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/256) that could solve these use cases by defining so called fragments, but I dont believe it will be standardized in OpenAPI anytime soon.

Is it really a bad thing to use POST in such cases? From my understanding, POST is used when data is mutated, however it gives us:

- ++ ability to do validate very soon, if all parameters of specific search request are valid and not in controller/service layer
- ++ makes URI more readable (can be used with along filtering)
- -- not able to save it in bookmarks
- -- for testing you need Postman/curl/...

So basically I would have something like this:

```
POST /stores?country=US
{
    "nearLocation": { "lat": 10, "lon": 10, "radius": "10km" }
}
```

instead of

```
GET /stores?country=US&lat=10&lon=10&radius=10km
```

which would require to validate the fields in controller and could not be defined in the openapi file.

What do you think, is it really a bad practice to move some fields to POST? I think we should differentiate between **filtering** and **searching**. You can filter enums, strings etc. and you can search with geospatial requests, date range requests where the comparator is not just `equal`. Am I thinking right?

Comment: Get will accept a form body. Additionally why not `/stores/us/(10,10)+10km`

Comment: Or a more URL friendly format like MGRS or UTM for urls: /stores/us/15SUD5505229951,10km

Comment: Related: [What is the correct way to pass JSON objects in an http request when a GET request is most appropriate?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/315544)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me say that they can both be used for this purpose.  As the complexity of your request goes up, the more you need a body instead of a parameter list on the URL.  We can better define your example.

A couple critiques:

- With coordinates, country is superfluous.  It can be discovered by testing the point against the country polygons
- What happens if the country is specified as UK, but the coordinates are for US?  Do you return no results because the combination is not valid or return the results for the coordinate?

First, making use of well defined standards like GeoJSON helps your application integrate out of the box with many tools.  For example your search could look like this:

```
POST /stores/search
{
  "radius": 10km,
  "location": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [125.6, 10.1]
  }
}
```

That translates more directly to a GET URL like the following (parameter names are same as JSON object):

```
GET /stores/search?radius=10km&location=[125.6,10.1]
```

But you could also encode the URL so it is all part of the request and use fancy routing to convert it into parameters you are using.  An example would be something that looks like this:

```
GET /stores/geosearch/[125.6,10.1](10km)
```

You'll also noticed that I added an action endpoint there for `search` or `geosearch` as opposed to the root `/stores` URL since by REST conventions that is where you would upload new records.

As to `GET` or `POST`, you have trade-offs:

- Some proxies are set up to prevent `POST` or any other modifying verb in an effort to avoid spilling proprietary data.  It's a lot less common now, but for very conservative entities it can be a thing.
- `GET` is *technically* more correct since you are not modifying data, but...
- As you have more and more parameters and the complexity of your search criteria goes up, you **must** switch to `POST` at a certain point.  Many servers have URL length limitations.

Comment: I think after three years it is very good time to accept this answer. It got just better and better after so much time.